# Change floating <ion-label> on Android device from blue to white

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there a way to change the colour of the floated label in an ionic project? I.e. the colour of the label when the input field has focus.

On iOS my  when floating is the colour that I give it, but on Android devices the label gets changed to a blue colour when it floats.

In my code I use:

```
<ion-label color="white" class="login-label" floating>
```

and:

```
.login-label:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: You could detect the UserAgent using javascript and change the style when in android.

Comment: Not sure how to do what you suggest. What style am I changing? How do I know when the associated field of the label has focus?

Comment: Alright. I have posted an answer below on how to do it. Let me know if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it & both needs javascript. This cannot be done only using CSS.

Firstly you could use javascript to detect the user agent if its android.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
   ...add a class OR change color directly as shown below..
}
```

Second, if android you could add a class to your body(`.android`) & change the style in your CSS using that class(`.android .login-label:focus`) OR just use javascript directly to change the color on focus.

```
if(isAndroid) {
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName("login-label")[0];
  input.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    this.style.color = "white";  
  });
}
```

**Update:**

Binding the color property to the element worked:

```
<ion-label [style.color]="labelColor" color="white" class="login-label" floating>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me because it is the ion-input field that has focus and not the ion-label

Comment: Alright, you mean you need to change the color of the `<ion-label>` on the focus of the corresponding input ? Also did you try the first method in that case ? (adding class to the body if android and changing the styles)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. Neither options work for me.

Comment: do you have a link to your app for me to check & debug ?

Comment: Thanks for the offer Nikhil but I don't have a link I can share.

Comment: Update: By making a few changes to what you suggested I got it to work! Couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: Happy to help, maybe you could share your findings and accept the answer so it can help others as well.

Comment: I did this in the end: <ion-label [style.color]="labelColor" color="white" class="login-label" floating> and set labelColor to "white" in my ts file.

Comment: Ok, you bound the property to the element then. Ok I will update the answer